# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /~/.vmc/target

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, cloud-foundry

I have installed **cloudfoundry** in my **Ubuntu 12.04** with **ruby 1.9.3**. Also I haved created a tunnel with a **VM**. But when run this command `vmc target api.vcap.me` I will have this error: 
`http://api.vcap.me... FAILED
CFoundry::TargetRefused: target refused connection (Connection refused - connect(2))
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash`

Also when I have run the comand: `vmc target` I received this error:
`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /home/sellami/.vmc/target`

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Try to setup target URL, for example execute command:

```
prompt$vmc target http://api.cloudfoundry.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you turn to Google Group vcap-dev for any related questions. https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev